# Need to delete data from dead phone?

Tags: mobile-data

I have Samsung Galaxy phone. Now its dead. I tried lots of combinations and now I'm going to send it to India. In India it will get repaired but I don't want anybody to get the data, messages or media files which is in internal memory. But as its not charging, I can't delete data directly. How can I delete media files specially from internal phone memory from my dead phone?

Comment: What do you mean by dead...Not Charging Are you able to connect it to your System?

Answer (score 2):

If you can charge a little  or arrange a new battry I guess you can do it by wiping data in recovery mode.

- To do so hold the volume up, home button and power button simultaneously.
- Once you are in Recovery Mode Scroll to wipe data/factory reset by pressing the Volume down button.

THATS IT.

Answer (score 0):

Had a look around for you, I've never imagined it to be possible to retrieve data from a dead phone without external storage inside the phone i.e SD Card, then I stumbled across [this article](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/108121/How+to+recover+%28internal+data+from%29+completely+dead-powerless+phone). A user commented something which i think you may find useful. I take no credit for this answer, try at your own peril.

> WARNING! - Refurbished only means you will get a working phone back.
>
> Even if they guarantee to return it with your data intact, be VERY
>   CAREFUL! they are just telephone call handlers and do not know for
>   sure what will happen, also people do not tick all the correct boxes
>   and others do not look at all the boxes, so you could loose out those
>   ways!
>
> I am very surprised that there is no information on this subject.
>
> It must have been an issue for 1000's of people over the past few
>   years.
>
> My problem is that "back up has stopped", would not re-install, and I
>   could not find out why (it said memory, but there was loads free -
>   since found it was talking about Dalvik).
>
> Over the weeks I built up a collection of useful information and
>   photos which I do not want to loose.
>
> I am assuming yours is an Android phone, but even if it's a Windows
>   phone, the principle is still probably the same.
>
> It appears to be possible to recover files from the internal memory of
>   a dead phone using a PC, free software and USB cable.
>
> The principle is start the Flashing process, BUT do not Flash the
>   phone, because I can not be sure it would not destroy your data /
>   files.
>
> When at the stage to be able to Flash the phone, effectively your PC
>   thinks it is communicating have a "USB memory device".
>
> This is achieved by removing the phones USB driver and substituting
>   another driver (to enable the Flashing process).
>
> I've not had the time to spend on it that I need.
>
> I will come back when I do finish ...
>
> BUT do not wait for me, there seems to be too many things going wrong,
>   and the most important get done first. Which is why I have things
>   waiting for over 1 year now.
>
> One problem I have is that Windows keeps throwing out the
>   "substitution USB driver" and replacing it with the original phone USB
>   driver.
>
> Windows thinks the phones driver is more suitable, so automatically
>   re-installs it.
>
> I know the issue, I've had it several times previously with the
>   "unknown device USB driver" (a crash causes the driver change). I just
>   need to find the "Windows stored back up driver", delete it, then
>   Windows will happily accept the "substitution driver".
>
> Ahhh, the joys of owning a MS Windows computer :-(
>
> Some usefull software names :-
>
> USB VCOM Driver
>
> Windows drivers - A25_USB_VCOM_Drivers
>
> usbdeview_droidtricks
>
> Some useful search terms :-
>
> brick
>
> unbrick
>
> flash rom
>
> SP Flash Tool exe v3 (not to use, but the process' before is what's
>   wanted).
>
> Searches with search engines (Google, Yahoo, etc.), also You Tube (I
>   could only find Flashing, but as previously, it's the process up to
>   the "Flashing point" that you are interested in).
>
> Sorry it's unfinished information, but at least it gives you hope and
>   some where to start.
>
> Data Recovery firms will be able to recovery the data / files and some
>   are open to "please help, I'm skint ...", by reducing their prices to
>   a poor private person, but they will not do it for free.
>
> So good luck to all of us.

And this gentlemen in the comments of said post found a company willing to retrieve information from a dead phone, this could be worth a shot prior to sending it to India.

> Hi Maria, sorry for the late response. They are called http://iekspert.dk/ or > iexpert.dk - try and write to them.

Just have a look and see what you find.